# Is it possible to destroy a button or checkbox when it is clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter, frontend

I am currently using tkinter to build a GUI and one of the functionalities I was hoping to achieve with the buttons was if it can be destroyed when it is clicked. I tried something along the lines of:

```
button = Button(window, text="hello", command=button.destroy()
```

This doesn't work as I'm getting the error:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'button' referenced before assignment.`

Are there are workarounds to accomplish a task like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save a reference to the button, and then call the `destroy` method on the button. Here's one way:

```
button = Button(window, text="hello")
button.configure(command=button.destroy)
```

The problem in your code is that you're trying to use `button` before the button has been created. Creating the button and then configuring the button in a separate step works around that problem since `button` exists by the time the second line is called.

Also notice that `command` is set to `button.destroy`, not `button.destroy()`. With the parenthesis, you're going to immediately call the method instead of assigning the command to the button.

Comment: Thank you, Bryan! I actually tried this method but didn't realize it was important to call the function without the parantheses. Kudos!

Answer (score -2):

That depends.. there is the `.grid_forget` method (or `.pack_forget` using pack instead of grid) if you don't want to delete permanently the widget (you can re-add it with .grid), and also the `.grid_remove` or `pack.remove`, but otherwise I suggest you to use `.destroy()`.

Comment: Forgot to add the fact that using .destroy() doesn't work. Edited my original post.